# My HP Compaq Laptop froze, then was erased completely, and doesn't do anything now; just shows disk error message

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, laptop

I was in the process of updating my system because Windows XP no longer has support for that system. During the updates, my laptop powered down and back on again, but then it started repeating that reboot process. I have tried everything I can to fix this and after trying everything to fix it the hard drive was erased and now it is showing the current disk error message,

> Non-System Disk or Disk error, Strike any key when done.

So, how can I fix this problem now? Is there a way that I can install a newer, more recently update system so that I may use my laptop again?

I am a student and this couldn't have happened at a worse time for me.

Comment: Download Windows XP SP3 ISO, boot to installation environment, install Windows XP, done. Of course you should also replace your HDD before you do that.   If you were installing a different version of Windows, install that, your previous (current) installation is gone and cannot be recovered.

Answer (score 0):

You have a dated system, but it can still be usable.  You have a few unanswered questions like:

> I was in the process of updating my system

How were you going about doing this?  Was it through fixed media like a cdrom or a dvd, or through usb or a downloaded program?
What was the software?

Putting those topics aside for now, you have a computer with--we can assume--a still working hard drive but one that has no operating system on it.

What you'll need now is a rescue cd or usb drive with a bootcd or iso.

One such example of this is Hiren's bootcd.
http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/ is the place to download.
http://www.hirensbootcd.org/burning/ will walk you through burning rescue media.
http://www.hirensbootcd.org/usb-booting/ along with http://www.hirensbootcd.org/change-the-boot-order-in-bios/ 
covers making a bootable usb drive and if your bios can--enabling booting from usb drives.

After you've created suitable media you can then do essential things like format, partition, copy bootloaders,
undelete files, backup MBRs and partition tables, download linux disto iso's in order to create a working system.